# No 'output' extra specified Exception

Tags: gallery, crop

I use the Google Photo app to pick gallery photo and then when I crop the picture and save, it catches an exception, Here is my code :

```
goto_picture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_ZOOM);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PHOTO_GRAPH) {
            startPhotoZoom(Uri.fromFile(file));
            String imagePath = SystemUtils.getSDPath() + "/temp.jpg";
            File picture = new File(imagePath);
            if (picture.exists()) {
                pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                ImageUtils.SaveCacheBitmap(pictureBitmap);
                rvEditAvatar.setImageBitmap(pictureBitmap);

            }
        }
        if (requestCode == PHOTO_ZOOM) {
            startPhotoZoom(data.getData());
        }

        if (requestCode == PHOTO_RESULT) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                pictureBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        stream);
                ImageUtils.SaveCacheBitmap(pictureBitmap);
                rvEditAvatar.setImageBitmap(pictureBitmap);
            }
        }

    } 
}

public void startPhotoZoom(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 180);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 180);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_RESULT);
}
```

Logcat:

> Process: com.google.android.apps.photos, PID: 7031
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.photoeditor.intents.EditActivity}:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No 'output' extra specified
>   and can not save to specified inputUri:
>   content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F72072/ACTUAL

Answer (score 0):

As the exception said, you have to specify output extra like the following code.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, someOutPutPath);
```

And return data is not secure in case of big image cropped which may cause crash. I think that's why it forces you to use an output extra but not the data directly. So you may set the return-data to false as well:

```
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem today, and solved by double check the data pass-back.I test following code on both Android L and Android 4. On Android L the `fileUri` is not empty while pre Android L we got `fileUri` null(in this case, I got the bitmap by simply `getData`).

```
private Bitmap decodeBitmapFromCrop(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap photo = null;
    if (extras != null) {
        photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
    } else {
        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        if (fileUri != null) {
            try {
                photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                XXLog.d(TAG, "Media.getBitmap", e);
            }
        }


    }
    return photo;
}
```